# ReactJS: Argument of type unknown is not assignable to parameter of type SetStateAction<string> from filereader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, filereader

I want to why my code is not working and causing me this error `Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<string>'. Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '(prevState: string) => string'.ts(2345)`.

This error is from this code `setBaseImage(base64);` of this function:

```
    const uploadImage = async (e: any) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const base64 = await convertBase64(file);
    setBaseImage(base64);
  };
```

Current code:

```
    const [baseImage, setBaseImage] = useState("");
const convertBase64 = (file: any) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

      fileReader.onload = () => {
        resolve(fileReader.result);
      };

      fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
        reject(error);
      };
    });
  };
```

I just follow this tutorial [source of the code](https://github.com/Rinlama/react-howtoseries/blob/imagetobase64Tut/src/App.js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Already solve the issue by updating this line of code:

```
setBaseImage(String(base64));
```